# React Native Textinput Flickers when using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, textinput

In my react native app, contains multiple TextInputs for a form which are rendered like this:

```
{this.props.steps.map(step, index) => (
  <TextInput
    multiline={true}
    value={this.props.steps[index]}
    placeholder="Enter Step"
    onChangeText={value => this.handleFieldChange(value, index)}
    style={{ padding: 10, fontSize: 15 }}
  />
)}
```

In the `onChangeText` function, the value of the textinput is edited using redux and the form is validated as so:

```
handleFieldChange = async (value, index) => {
  var steps = this.props.steps;
  steps[index]= value;
  store.dispatch(updateSteps({ steps: steps }));
  this.validateForm();
};
```

This means the TextInput's value doesn't get updated immediately so when the user types relatively fast, the it flickers.

Can someone suggest how to make the Text Input get updated more smoothly?

Comment: can you add expo snack?
and anyhow you should shallow copy redux store before modifying `var steps = [...this.props.steps]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After testing for a while, I realised that it was nothing to do with the onChangeText function. I found that the TextInput only flickered after its contents exceeded the initial width of the component. Therefore making the TextInput the full width of the screen and adding `textAlign` to center the input solved the issue.

```
var width = Dimensions.get("window").width

<TextInput
  multiline={true}
  value={this.props.steps[index]}
  placeholder="Enter Step"
  onChangeText={value => this.handleFieldChange(value, index)}
  style={{ width: width, padding: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: "center" }}
/>
```

This issue didn't occur if the TextInput was the only component in the screen, but only when it was nested in several Views as was the case here. However, I have no idea what is the direct cause of this error.

Comment: dude - thank you for coming back to answer your question. I was a bit stuck here and dont want to know how long I would have gone before figuring that out

Answer (score 0):

In the rendering `step` could be used (irrelevant, I know) and a `key` would be used, I would change this

```
value={this.props.steps[index]}
```

in

```
value={step}
key={index}
```

As already commented, in `handleFieldChange` you are changing `props` in a bad way, this:

```
var steps = this.props.steps;
```

needs to be changed in:

```
var steps = [...this.props.steps];
```

More than this I see no evidence why `handleFieldChange` needs to be an `async` function, I would remove `async` from its declaration.

Last, the root source of the problem could be in `updateSteps` or in `validateForm`...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the cause was not setting the width of the text input component. Setting it to "100%" worked so well for me. Using another value will also work.